# Make Custom link visible only to specific group of users

Tags: profile, permission-sets, home-page-component, custom-link, custom-permission

I want to show custom link(visualforce page) on Home page available to only to specific group of people.I don't see an  option to assign it via permission set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can do it via the `$Permission` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm). Note the global variable checks if the running user has a `Custom Permission`, not a `PermissionSetAssignment`. Create a `Visualforce Homepage Component` as follows:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:outputLink rendered="{!$Permission.ShouldSeeHomepageLink}"
        value="{!$Page.HomepageLink}">{!$Label.HomepageLinkText}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you,It works but for other users who doesn't have access to Custom Permission they see Visualforce page with the code

Comment: @sfdc I don't understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: @sfdc It looks like the user you are testing with has `Development Mode` enabled. Disable it from their user record (there should be a `Development Mode` checkbox).